# WPF modeless dialog renders textbox uneditable

Tags: wpf, textbox, .net-3.5, modeless

A WPF form that I launch from a WinForms window shows up with all textboxes as uneditable when it's launched as a modeless dialog. It works well when it's a modal window. I'm still able to type spaces or paste text. But regular typing doesn't work. I'm using 3.5 with SP1. Would anybody know how to resolve this?

Comment: Yeah, can you post some code? Question is not much clear the way it is now to think about an answer.

Comment: If I do a wpfUI.Show() instead of wpfUI.ShowDialog(), the textboxes on my wpfUI window cannot be typed into. The code can't get any simpler than that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to make sure to call [ElementHost.EnableModelessKeyboardInterop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.enablemodelesskeyboardinterop.aspx) for your WPF Window. This hooks up the WPF message loop to allow keyboard input.

Comment: I've got a weird issue now. I am opening my WPF UI from an MS Excel as an add-in too. The EnableModelessKeyboardInterop doesn't work there. Whenever I try to edit my WPF textbox, the focus shifts to Excel and the keyboard input is generated on Excel. Any ideas on how to fix this?

This is what I found for it, but I hope this is not the only solution: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andreww/archive/2009/02/24/message-hooks-in-add-ins.aspx

Comment: @Prakash - Sorry, I don't have any experience with Excel plugins. You may want to as this as another question.