# WPF modeless dialog from MS Excel add-in

Tags: wpf, excel, textbox, .net-3.5

A WPF form that I launch from a WinForms window showed up with all textboxes 
as uneditable when launched as a modeless dialog. I used 
`ElementHost.EnableModelessKeyboardInterop` to tackle the issue & it worked there.

I am also opening the same WPF UI from an MS Excel as an add-in. 
The `EnableModelessKeyboardInterop` hack doesn't work there. Whenever I try to 
edit my WPF textbox, the focus shifts to Excel and the keyboard input 
is rendered on Excel instead of on my WPF textbox. Any ideas on how to fix this?

P.S. - This is in continuation to my earlier question on SO: [WPF modeless dialog renders textbox uneditable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818294/wpf-modeless-dialog-renders-textbox-uneditable)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Solved it, courtesy of this link: [Running WPF Application with Multiple UI Threads](http://eprystupa.wordpress.com/2008/07/28/running-wpf-application-with-multiple-ui-threads/)

```
         var thread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                var wpfWindow = new WPFWindow();
                wpfWindow.Show();
                wpfWindow.Closed += (sender2, e2) => wpfWindow.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();

                Dispatcher.Run();
            });

            thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            thread.Start();
```

Comment: `EnableModelessKeyboardInterop` indeed does not work when showing modeless WPF windows from Excel. To be able to reuse this code, I created a generic static method that can be called for any WPF window. I also tried extension methods, but the instance of the WPF Window _must_ be created in the thread start delegate; with an extension method, an instance would already have been created.